# Only one tello drone flies when running tello swarm

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I try to run tello swarm and I am inspired by [this article](https://medium.com/@henrymound/adventures-with-dji-ryze-tello-controlling-a-tello-swarm-1bce7d4e045d). However, only one tello drone can fly.

I have done some experiments to make sure each network interface
(in my cases, one notebook wifi adapter and two usb wifi dongles)
can successfully interact with any tello (I have three in total)
if python code is modified to only try to connect one tello.
Unfortunately, when I try to interact two tellos at the same time
(as you did in this tutorial), only one tello fly each time. The codes is as follows. The operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.

```
import socket
import time

drone1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
drone1.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 2, 'wlp2s0'.encode())

drone2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
drone2.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 2, 'wlxf8788c004f0'.encode())

drone1.sendto('command'.encode(), 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
drone2.sendto('command'.encode(), 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))

drone1.sendto('takeoff'.encode(), 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
drone2.sendto('takeoff'.encode(), 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))

time.sleep(5)

drone1.sendto('command'.encode(), 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
drone2.sendto('command'.encode(), 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))

drone1.sendto('land'.encode(), 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
drone2.sendto('land'.encode(), 0, ('192.168.10.1', 8889))
```

I would appreciate it very much if anyone could give me some suggestions.

Comment: You're sending everything to the same address 192.168.10.1. Do they indeed have the same address?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. To let a tello drone fly, a wifi interface of my notebook have to connect to the tello drone. Then the tello drone will assign a IP to the interface while the drone takes 192.168.10.1. Therefore, two tello drones all takes 192.168.10.1 in their respective network. In addition, each of the two wifi interfaces on my notebook are assigned 192.168.10.3 by the respective tello drone. Is it possible all instructions are sent to the same interface (and the same tello drone)?